# Unit Testing in API ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I would like to make some unit-test about all my methods, (DELETE, PUT, POST ETC..) but i don't know how can i instanciate my clases in unit, now i have this in unit class:

```
 //Arrange
 var mockRepo = new Mock<IRebelRepository>();
 var controller = new RebelsController(mockRepo.Object);
 //Act
 var rebel = controller.Delete(2);
```

but now i want to check if the id is correct or not watching the response of my API (OK or BadResponse)

```
public ActionResult<Rebel> Delete(int id)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Start of RebelsController.Delete()");
            var result = new ApiResult();
            ActionResult response = null;
            _logger.LogDebug($"Trying to delete rebel ID: {id}");

            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("There was a problem deleting rebel, invalid data");
                    result.Message = "Invalid rebel information.";
                    result.IsError = true;
                    response = BadRequest(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (id > 0)
                    {
                        var filteredRebel = _rebelRepository.GetRebelById(id);

                        if (filteredRebel == null)
                        {
                            _logger.LogWarning($"The rebel {id} was not found");
                            result.Message = $"The rebel with id {id} has not been found";
                            result.IsError = true;

                            response = BadRequest(result);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _rebelRepository.DeleteRebel(filteredRebel);
                            result.Message = "Rebel deleted correctly";
                            _logger.LogDebug($"Rebel {id} sucessfully deleted");

                            response = Ok(result);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("An error occurred while Deleted method was running, error :" + ex.Message);
                result.Message = "Error on Delete";
                result.IsError = true;
                response = BadRequest(result);
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("End of RebelsController.Delete()");
            return response;
        }
```

How can i make unit testing in APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `response` depends on the rebel returned from `GetRebelById`, hence you should set up expected result when calling this function with test Id, for example

```
var mockRepo = new Mock<IRebelRepository>();
var testId = 2;
mockRepo.Setup(r => r.GetRebelById(testId)).Returns(new Rebel {Id = testId});
var controller = new RebelsController(mockRepo.Object);

var result = controller.Delete(testId);

var actionResult = result.Result;
Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(actionResult);
var apiResult = (actionResult as OkObjectResult).Value as ApiResult;
Assert.NotNull(apiResult);
Assert.Equal("Rebel deleted correctly", apiResult.Message);

// should put in another test
var notFoundId = 500;
var result2 = controller.Delete(notFoundId);
var actionResult2 = result2.Result;
Assert.IsType<BadRequestObjectResult>(actionResult2);
```

Comment: And now? how can i continue the testing? what asert can i put?

Comment: The cast ´var rebel = (actionResult as OkObjectResult).Value as Rebel;´ return null

Comment: What's your `ApiResult`?

Comment: i changed the Ok() by OK(FilteredRebel) and nothing, my ApiResult is a model that can write data, message and a itsError bool: public class ApiResult
    {
        public object Data { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public bool IsError { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Because you return an `ActionResult` of an `ApiResult`, the return type of `Delete` method in the controller should be `ActionResult<ApiResult>`, I have updated my code again.

Comment: Ahh okay, it works well now, but now if i try to put testID = 500, it works too, and should not cause i don't have any register with id = 500

Comment: If you just set `testId=500` and nothing else, it works well because all the setup relates to this `testId`. See my updated code.

Comment: @sergiodiaz: Could you mark my answer as accepted or upvote it?